# Does PetaPoco support component mapping?

Tags: c#, umbraco, petapoco

As I am new to PetaPoco and normaly user to NHIbernate I wonder if and how I can map components with petapoco.

Two classes:

```
[ExplicitColumns]
public class Event{
     [Column]
     public int Id {get;set;}
     [Column]
     public DateTime Start {get;set;}
     [Column]
     public DateTime Start {get;set;}
     ...
     [???]
     public EventLocation Location {get;set;}
}

[ExplicitColumns]
public class EventLocation{
     [Column]
     public int Id {get;set;}
     [Column]
     public string Name {get;set;}
     [Column]
     public string Street {get;set;}
     [Column]
     public string Zip {get;set;}
     [Column]
     public string City {get;set;}
}
```

Is there any way to map this with PetaPoco? For now the eventlocation is not persisted. Do I have to write a custom componentmapper?

---

Update: I tried tims solution (respectivly found an analog solution myself) but now I am facing problems with properties having the same name. The Id of the `EventLocations` is set correctly but not for the `Event` reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PetaPoco does support multi-poco queries. there's a blog with some example code here: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/desktopdev/mstech/csharp/more-petapoco-id-s-and/

In theory, assuming you decorate your Location property with the `[ResultColumn]` attribute you should be able to do something like this (note, this is just illustrative example code, may not actually work for your database):

```
var results = db.Query<Event, EventLocation>(@"
                          SELECT Event.*, EventLocation.* 
                          FROM Event 
                            INNER JOIN EventLocation ON Event.LocationID = EventLocation.Id );
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried almost exactly the same. The Problem I got, was with properties having the same names. I'll update the original question.

Comment: I got it working with listing all the columns explicitly.